# TypeScript build error: Build:An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript

I use VS2017 and TypeScript 2.5.3.

The .ts code looks as following:

```
class LossEnergyCalculation {

    async initLossEnergyCalculation(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/LossEnergyCalculation/GetOilFieldList");
            const oilFieldsData = await response.json();
    }
    ...
}
```

In project's properties in TypeScript Build section I have set:

```
TypeScript version: 2.5
ECMAScript version: ECMAScript 5
JSX compilation in TSX files: None
Module System: CommonJS
```

I don't have tsconfig.json file.

When I build the project the following error appears:

```
Build:An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
```

How to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the `lib` option to include the `Promise` declarations. At runtime you will also need a library for promises if your runtime does not have built-in support for them.

To specify the libs you will need a tsconfig.json. From what you specify in the question. This should be equivalent to your current config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015.promise", "es5", "dom" ]
  }
}
```

**NOTE** I included just the `es2015.promise` from `es2015` and `es5` for the rest of the runtime declarations. This ensures that you don't get features of `es2015` you should not be using and you only get the promises you need. Also just because you have the `es2015.priomise` lib included does not mean the runtime will have promises, that should be handled separately.

Comment: I've added tsconfig.json file as you suggested, but have the same error.

Comment: The tsconfig.json file and my .ts file are in the same Scripts folder.

Comment: Where did you save it ? The root of the application ? If you go to project settings are the options in typescript build deactivated ? (If they are not it means tsconfig.json is not taken into account)

Comment: Should I download something else from npm?

Comment: It should be in the rrot of the application not in the same folder as the ts

Comment: If you are using the build process in VS, no extra npm packages should be required ..

Comment: I've saved it in Scripts sub-folder of root folder where my .ts file is. The project's settings are deactivated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162800/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-tesicg).

Comment: I've moved tsconfig.json file to root folder and still have the same error.

Comment: The project you sent me was built successfully, but my project was not. I have no idea why.